# How to invalidate session of one application while switching to other application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am building application using spring + spring security + cas.

CAS provides once login to access multiple applications. Now my problem is at the time of logout session is not invalidating for all the applications integrated in CAS.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement and turn on the CAS single logout feature. When you do that upon cas logout all other applications will be reached in and their session will be invalidated